# handling video after video is buffered in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

To be precise I need to handle my WEBAPP video after the video is buffered.
Through googling I found for buffering `event handler` would be:

```
video.onwaiting = function(){
    $(".buffering").show();
};
```

The `buffereing` element is a loader which appears when the video needs to buffer.

Now I need to handle the video after it's buffered like for 5 seconds, So I could use `$("buffering").hide();` to hide my `buffering`.

So far I'm doing:

```
video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var range = 0;
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;

    while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
        range += 1;
    }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
    var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;
    val = loadPercentage*100;
});
```

If you may, Why am I getting this error:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
>   on line `while();`

So I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to handle the video after 5 second of it's duration is buffered.

Regards:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first `progress` event, the TimeRanges returned by `buffered` is empty. So requesting its start or end will throw the IndexSize error.

Also, the parameter to `TimeRanges.start` and `TimeRanges.end` is the index of the required timeRange, it can't be below 0 and above TimeRanges.length, that you can use instead of your while loop :

```js
video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;
    if(!bf.length){
      return;
      }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(0) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(bf.length-1) / this.duration;
    var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;
    var val = loadPercentage*100;
    console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4" muted="true" controls></video>
```

Comment: Thanks. And do you know how to find if the video is buffered for 5 seconds or so?

Comment: @akdsfjakls `bf.end(bf.length-1) - bf.start(0) > 5` ?

Comment: would be like this: `if((bf.end(bf.length-1)-bf.start(0))>5){
         $('.buffering').hide();
        }`